# Bayesian linear regression - posterior distribution

Tags: regression, bayesian, normal-distribution

This is about bayesian linear regression. In this link http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/gaussianprocess/node2.html there's a derivation for

[image]

=

[image: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/gaussianprocess/img38.png]
[image]

The part that I don't understand is how it is that $p(y|x^*,w) = w^Tx^*$?

$x^*$ is a new data point and $y^*$ is its predicted value.

Comment: It isn't true.  Consider $w=-1$ and $x^*=1$; that would generate a negative value for $p(y|\cdot)$.

Comment: I think the link is being notationally very sloppy at that point; I believe they mean the expected value of $y|x^*,w$, not the probability density, and they certainly don't mean that the integral equals the formula for a Normal distribution.  Either that or the $w^Tx^*$ is a major typographical error.